# Is there any good code analysis/refactoring tools for T-SQL besides RedGate?

Tags: t-sql, refactoring

I've used RedGate in the past, but the feature-to-price ratio really sucks. At $369 for one-year it is far too expensive when compated to much richer applications like CodeRush and Resharper.

Comment: +1 would like to know too. The only I know so far are from RedGate too...

Answer (score 1):

SQL Enlight

http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/features.php